# segmentation fault (core dumped) occurs when I alter a string

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to build a function in C that changes the characters 'f' and/or 'o' of a string to 'x'. For some reason I keep getting a segmentation fault (core dumped) when i run the program, even though it compiles without issue. I understand that a segmentation fault occurs when the program tries to access a location in memory that it doesn't have access to, however, I don't see what in my code could be causing this issue. here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void censor(char p[]);

int main(){


    censor("foodfool");
    return 0;
}

void censor(char p[]){

    int i;
    for(i = 0;p[i] != '\0';i++){
        if(p[i] == 'f' || p[i] == 'o')
            p[i] = 'x';
        printf("%c", p[i]);     

    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: You are using an environment that doesn't permit you to modify string literals.  Change your program to read strings from stdin, using `fgets`, and it will work.

Comment: Replace `censor("foodfool");` with `char s[] = "foodfool"; censor(s);`

Comment: I wonder why it wasn't a type error. "cannot convert const char * to char *" or something like that

Comment: @NieDzejkob It would have been in C++, and some compilers can make it be one in C as well (e.g. gcc/clang's `-Wwrite-strings` option does exactly this).  It's an intentional backward compatiblity wart in the standard.  I highly recommend using `-Wwrite-strings` or equivalent for new code, but turning it on for old code can be months of work for very little gain.

Comment: @zwol I highly recommend using `-Wall -Wextra` and for production, `-Werror`.

Comment: @NieDzejkob Those are good _also_, but none of them turns on `-Wwrite-strings`.

Comment: Seconding compiling with `-Wall`

Answer (score 2):

The string `"foodfool"` is a compile-time constant, which you cannot modify. Replace it with a `char` array (`char[]`) or heap-allocated `char` pointer (`char*`).

Comment: Thanx guys this was a great help!